# Abstract Algebra; Let $G = \{ \mathbf{Q} + \mathbf{Q}i \} \ \{0 \} = \{ a + bi \in \mathbf{C} | a, b \in \mathbf{Q}, a + bi \neq 0 \}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to prove $\langle G,* \rangle$ is a group, here i am confused to show it is a binary operation. In my idea, if there exist $a,b \in \mathbf{Q}$, then the multiplication of them will not in $G$. Or I have begun in wrong way?  May someone give me some hints? Thanks.